# Sqoop connection to MS SQL timeout

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

I am attempting to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using Sqoop. I have installed the JDBC driver from Microsoft by following the instructions for the [Sqoop Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27584) and the [JDBC Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21599). Next I attempt to list the databases on the server. I have tried the following commands:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST>' --username <USER> --password <PASS>
sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST>;username=<USER>;password=<PASS>'
sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST>;username=<USER>;password=<PASS>' --username <USER> --password <PASS>
```

Each of these commands produces the same error messages.

```
    13/01/02 10:44:52 ERROR sqoop.ConnFactory: Error loading ManagerFactory information from file <MY SQOOP DIRECTORY>/conf/managers.d/mssqoop-sqlserver: java.io.IOException: the content of connector file must be in form of key=value
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.addManagersFromFile(ConnFactory.java:219)
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.loadManagersFromConfDir(ConnFactory.java:294)
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.instantiateFactories(ConnFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.<init>(ConnFactory.java:62)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.ConnFactory.<init>(ConnFactory.java:36)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:200)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:44)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)

13/01/02 10:45:08 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host <HOST>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1033)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:665)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:56)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
```

I have connected to the database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to ensure the database is operation and that that the host/username/password are all correct. Additionally I have ensured that the port is open and that MSSQL is on the other side with the following.

```
sudo nmap -sS -p 1433 <HOST>

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-01-02 11:04 PST
Nmap scan report for <HOST> (<HOST IP>)
Host is up (0.00070s latency).
rDNS record for <HOST IP: <HOST FQDN>
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
1433/tcp filtered ms-sql-s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.33 seconds
```

Any suggestions on where I should go from here? I have not been able to find any documentation on this error. Thanks

I am currently attempting to verify that the SQL server is reachable using OSQL from FreeTDS. Will update this post with my findings.

Comment: Followup: I have determined that when using an incorrect username/password it will fail immediately meaning it is in fact somehow interacting with the server. SQL Profiler shows no connections however when using the correct username/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching and talking to many people I have determined that this issue is being caused by the port being blocked. I am still not 100% certain why this error in particular occurred. If I try with an invalid username or password it will successfully tell me that they are invalid. It is just when it comes to making the actual query that the port is restricted. Most likely different ports are used.